# Symfony doctrine update schema giving invalid default value for datetime

Tags: mysql, symfony

I've literally not had this problem before, but i am just trying to run doctrine:schema:update and i'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid
> default value for 'liked_date_time'

Here is the field in question in my entity

```
/**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default":"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $likedDateTime;
```

The query it generates:

```
CREATE TABLE user_post_like (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, post_id INT DEFAULT NULL, image_id INT DEFAULT NULL, user_id INT DEFAULT NULL, liked_date_time DATETIME(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, d  
  eleted TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, deleted_date_time DATETIME(6) DEFAULT NULL, INDEX IDX_65D6AA5C4B89032C (post_id), INDEX IDX_65D6AA5C3DA5256D (image_id), INDEX IDX_65D6AA5CA76ED395 (user_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb  
  4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I don't see anything wrong with this? It's always worked perfectly fine and all of a sudden it doesn't

I am using mysql 5.7 here with symfony 5 and doctrine 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

> If a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column definition includes an explicit
> fractional seconds precision value anywhere, the same value must be
> used throughout the column definition. This is permitted:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (
>   ts TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
> );
> ```
>
> This is not permitted:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (
>   ts TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
> );
> ```

The example that is not permitted shows two cases of a mismatched precision. The default has no precision. The on update argument has a precision, but not the same precision of the column.

The example also shows TIMESTAMP, but the same issue affects DATETIME.

I have no idea how to convince Doctrine to generate the correct DDL statement. But this is the meaning of the error. If I test your DDL statement with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)`, it works.

Comment: yeh my point here though, is i've never had to do that before, it's just randomly started happening

Comment: I doubt it's random. _Something_ changed. What changed? Code? Software versions? Configuration? Data? Environment?

Comment: no nothing has changed in the code, no software nothing, i literally just destroyed the db and the docker containers and re-loaded them all, came to rebuild the database and this started

Comment: Just a wild guess, try `options={"default":"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)"}`

Comment: i did try that but doctrine then treats it as a string not a constant

Comment: I found this thread, it sounds like Doctrine developers have been struggling for a long time to resolve timestamp precision issues. https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2873

Comment: thanks, it seems like it's doctrine generating the sql query incorrectly, but it has never done this before in the 6 years i've used it. I have posted on their github discussion

Comment: I have generated a migration to generate the entire database and i've manually replaced the bad query so now the tables generate. I am marking your answer as it is technically correct